# LibSVM performs much worse that LIBLINEAR

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I'm using both `LibSVM` and `LIBLINEAR` libraries in my program. `LIBLINEAR` gives pretty good results, but `LibSVM` with linear kernel performs much worse on the same problem with the same C parameter and `bias = 1` for `LIBLINEAR`.
 What could be the reason for that?
 Also `LinearSVC` class from scikit-learn performs even better than `LIBLINEAR`, whch is also surprising considering that it's a wrapper of `LIBLINEAR`.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Higher accuracy on the test set? What is your exact implementations, libraries used? You should elaborate more, because obviousyly, this should not take place if there is no implementation error

Comment: I'm trying to figure whether this is an implementation error or a peculiarity of the libraries.

Comment: By better I mean higher accuracy, of course. The difference is so big that it can't be explained by implementation details.

Comment: You should give much more details if you expect any answer. Without them, this question is useless - correctly used, these libraries give alsmot identical solutions. And by correctly I mean - with SAME parameters, `C` is not the only one - there is also maximum iteration count, the epsilon variable for numerical optimization etc.

Comment: Providing more details means debugging my code which is apparently not possible. Probably you're right and this question won't have any answer but I though that there could be some insight about the parameters etc.

Comment: You should at least state **exactly** which implementations (with version numbers!) of particular libraries you use, in what programming languages etc.

Comment: I'm using the latest versions (LIBLINEAR 1.93 and LibSVM 3.17) written in C. I made my wrapers for them in C++, which are very similiar and made almost by copy-paste as these libraries have very close interfaces. But the accuracies differ drastically (e.g. I get about 85% accuracy on the test set from LibLinear and less than 50% from LibSVM).

Comment: Less then 50% means a implementation error, because it means, that answering exact **opposite** of your model gets higher score. At least in the **binary** case, maybe we are talking abount mutli-class problem? This could explain something

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's a multiclass problem with about 10 classes, so 50% is not that low, but significantly lower than 85%.

Comment: I've made my own wrapper for one-vs-rest classification, internally it splits the problem into a set of binary problems and feeds them to LIBLINEAR or LibSVM. I also set the class weights reverse proportionally to the number of objects in them.

Comment: Without more details about all the parameters used, I can only say that if the data is separable to the extent that LIBLINEAR does it, then  there is something wrong with your libSVM setup. SVM algorithms may be slightly different, but specially linear kernels tend to give more or less the same result in all of them. I'm not familiar with LIBLINEAR, but is it possible that the definition of C in LIBLINEAR is different from libSVM's definition? C is rather arbitrary anyhow. Do an array search on the best C for libSVM and find the best accuracy.